# Yahoo UI integration with Spring MVC 3.0

Tags: arrays, angularjs, spring-mvc, yui, frontend

Please let me know the folder structure for integrating Yahoo UI with Spring MVC 3.0.

Please provide the link for sample application which has Yahoo UI with Spring MVC 3.0 .

Thanks,
Pravin.

Comment: If you're not hosting your own copy of YUI, there is no folder structure you need. Even if you are hosting your own copy, you can decide where you place YUI. It just needs to live somewhere which is accessible to clients. If you host it yourself, you should look at implementing a combo loader to prevent loading a large number of small files

Comment: Hi Barnyr.i have not yet started YUI with Spring MVC 3.0.Once done i will post. In angular we  keep all the angular code under webcontent->resource folder and html layout's under webcontent->web_inf->html folder.